# Android App crashes on Sign Up

Tags: java, android, sql

I am using SQL to store user data in the Android App. App is working fine but crashes when updating new user.
I am sharing my code.

```
SQLiteDatabase
                        data=openOrCreateDatabase("fun",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
                data.execSQL("create table if not exists tabl(sim varchar, name varchar, user varchar,password varchar)");
                String st="select * from tabl where user='"+mail+"'";
                Cursor cursor=data.rawQuery(st,null);
                if(cursor.getCount()>0)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Username already used!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    data.execSQL("insert into tabl values('"+simno+"',"+fname+"','"+mail+"','"+pass+"')");
                    Toast.makeText(Register.this, "Registered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent log=new Intent(Register.this,Sender.class);
                    startActivity(log);
                    finish();
                }
```

Comment: Show us the errors

Comment: You can't name your table `DATABASE`, because that's a reserved keyword.

Comment: App stops working after pressing Signup button.

Comment: this code is part of .java file of that app.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain keywords and reserved words that you can't just simple use to name your tables or other attributes, "Database" is one of them. Please change your table name to something else. This [link](https://sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) shows the full list.